# React native interactive map component

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, react-native, cross-platform

I have been looking for a simple interactive map for react native so that the user would be able to locate user's location using device's GPS sensor, and pin his/her current location manually.

Here is what I have already found:

[react-native-maps-google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps-google)

[react-native-open-maps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-open-maps)

[integrate-airbnb-google-maps-in-a-react-native-app](https://www.codementor.io/uokesita/integrate-airbnb-google-maps-in-a-react-native-app-dxjp5p5ed)

[react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps)

Unfortunately, all them are just rendering map with a predefined location.

Please consider that the best solution would be the one which is compatible with both Android and iOS platforms.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Using [React native maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps) after following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md)

You can do the following:
Add your imports and set a the initial coords

```
imports....
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
//maybe in the componentWillMount
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
      initialLocation: {
        latitude: xxxxxxxxxx,
        longitude: xxxxxxxxxx,
        latitudeDelta: xxxxxxxxxx,
        longitudeDelta:xxxxxxxxxx
      },
      locationChosen: false
    });
}
```

render mapView

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MapView
          initialRegion={this.state.initialLocation}
          ref={ref => this.map = ref}
        />
        <View>
          <Button 
             title="Locate Me" 
             onPress={this.currentLocationHandler} 
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Now your handler using  [React Native’s Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html):
(Don't forget to add to your android manifest the permissions to access to your location)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Using [getCurrentPosition](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#getcurrentposition)

```
currentLocationHandler = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
      const coordsEvent = {
        nativeEvent: {
          coordinate: {
            latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
            longitude: pos.coords.longitude
          }
        }
      };
      const coords = coordsEvent.nativeEvent.coordinate;
        this.map.animateToRegion({
          ...this.state.initialLocation,
          latitude: coords.latitude,
          longitude: coords.longitude
        });
   })
 }
```

With this you will be able to locate yourself on the map, then you can add a marker which will be easy following the examples on the repository.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank @Yanci, Since android 6 and newer versions require location run-time permission, I'd like to know how to handle that too.

Comment: Sorry for the delay @AtaIravani well I haven't had problems using this line in my AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> however you can refer to this link to find more information [PermissionsAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html)

Answer (score 0):

To create Map with user's current location, use [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps) and [React Native’s Geolocation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html).

You can find location and map marker example here: [MyLocationMapMarker](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/MyLocationMapMarker.js). Checkout the [other examples](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/tree/master/example/examples) too.